# Logging SSIS variable expressions

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am loading about 40 files to Oracle from my SSIS ETL package. At the end of each files load process, I run a SQL query to to perform a Type-2 update for old data expiration.

The SQL Query is stored in a variable called `ExpireOldRecordsQuery` which is built at runtime so the `EvaluateAsExpression` property is set to `TRUE` and the Expression goes something like this

`"Update MyTable Set ExpiredOn = SYSDATE Where ExpiredOn IS NULL AND DownloadID <> " + @User::CurrentDownloadId`

I want to log the actual query from the `ExpireOldRecordsQuery` variable.

How do I make SSIS log what the expression is evaluated to?

Answer (score 1):

Any time your variable is referenced it will evaluate to the current value.  This means, the value of ExpireOldRecordsQuery will always equal the string plus the current value of @User::CurrentDownLoadId.

The ExpireOldRecordsQuery variable can be used like any other variable,  so you can log it's value.  If you're using SSIS logging, you can use the FireInformation() function in a Script Task to send the variable information to the SSIS log.

Comment: *"you can use the FireInformation() function in a Script Task"* As somebody who is new to SSIS I found this advice promising but unhelpful. Googling for `SSIS+FireInformation()+logfile` didn't up anything immediately useful. Do I need to write something in VB or C# to make this happen?